# Data Model structure for farm related project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, data-modeling, datamodel

I am currently trying to figure out a data model and struggling as its getting quite complex. What I've got so far is explained below. I'm going to implement this in an ASP.NET CORE MVC app to help with managing the harvest remotely.

The data model is as follows: Farms can have multiple fields, each field can have multiple types of crop. Each farm can also have multiple harvests with different crops to which I need to be able to store information about the total crop yield, for that harvest, that's specific to that farm. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Attempted data model -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkqxg.jpg

Edit - Sorry didn't specify how I would like an answer. The Entities as below:

I currently have -

```cs
public class Farm : IEntityBase<int>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Harvest> Harvests { get; set; }
        public Farm()
        {
            CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

public class Crop : IEntityBase<int>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
        public string CropName { get; set; }
        public Crop()
        {
            CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

public class Field : IEntityBase<int>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int FieldId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
        public int FieldSize { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Crop> Crops { get; set; }

        public Field()
        {
            CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

public class Harvest:IEntityBase<int>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
        public int FarmId { get; set; }
        public DateTime HarvestYear { get; set; }
        public Crop Crop { get; set; }
        public Harvest()
        {
            CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
            HarvestYear = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would you like your answer to be given? since your info is a picture

Comment: Yep I should have specified, please see my edit!

Comment: Ok so lets do a quick rundown. 1 farm can have many harvests, does 1 harvest only apply to a single farm? Next, 1 field can have many crops, can 1 crop be contained in many fields? Actually, would you mind giving a full description of which constraints should exist between your data models. Need a little more and I will assist you in building your schema

Comment: 1. Correct 1 harvest to a single farm. 2. Yes 1 crop to many fields. 

I will try a proper description, 5 mins!

Comment: You are on the right track, mostly. It's just a case of popping in 1 or 2 intermediary tables to facilitate your many-to-many relationships

Comment: Not sure how to explain it any better, just getting used to creating data models. What extra tables are we talking so I can try to get my head around it? Sadly can't send PMs on here.

Comment: @plowmountain, I think your code design is basically reasonable. As for the database, you only need to use `ef core code first` to automatically generate the corresponding structure in the database.